# Gradle Tasks Difference

Tags: gradle

What's the difference between the following two code snippets?

First:

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) << {
  from "folder/from"
  into "dest/folder"
}
```

Second:

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
  from "folder/from"
  into "dest/folder"
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In short, the first snippet is getting it wrong, and the second one is getting it right.

A Gradle build proceeds in three phases: initialization, configuration, and execution. Methods like `from` and `into` *configure* a task, hence they need to be invoked in the configuration phase. However, `<<` (which is a shortcut for `doLast`) adds a *task action* - it instructs the task what to do *if* and *when* it gets executed. In other words, the first snippet configures the task in the execution phase, and even worse, *after* its main (copy) action has been executed. Hence the configuration won't have any effect.

Typically, a task has *either* a type (which already brings along a task action) *or* a `<<` (for an ad-hoc task). There are legitimate uses cases for having both (doing a bit of custom work after the task's "main" work), but more often that not, it's a mistake where the task gets configured too late.

I generally recommend to use `doLast` instead of `<<`, because it's less cryptic and makes it easier to spot such mistakes. (Once you understand the concepts, it's kind of obvious that `task copyFiles(type: Copy) { doLast { from ... } }` is wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

The first block of code create a task and append an Action to it. A task is composed of actions which are instructions blocks run sequentially when the task is called

The second block create a task and configure it. These instructions are run in the gradle "configuration" lifecycle phase.

[here](http://gradleware.com/registered/books/building-and-testing/tasks.html#task-configuration) you find a clear explanation of the differences

[here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) you can find an in depth explanation of gradle tasks

[here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) is the gradle guide about lifecycle