# What is correct way to define tasks in Gradle plugin?

Tags: plugins, gradle

I'm trying to create my first Gradle plugin.
1. Add extension for properties: `project.extensions.create("abc", AbcExtension)`
2. Define copy task. When I define task following way

```
project.task("abcTask", type: Copy) {
  from project.abc.fromPath
  into project.abc.intoPath
}
```

project.abc.fromPath equals to `AbcExtension.fromPath` value - it doesn't read values from `build.gradle`.
When I define task following way

```
project.task("abcTask", type: Copy) << {
  from project.abc.fromPath
  into project.abc.intoPath
}
```

it always print `UP-TO-DATE` and doesn't run task.

Pls explain this behaviour and tell me what is correct way to define tasks in Gradle plugins (with `type` and `dependsOn` functionallity)

Comment: This question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632696/gradle-tasks-difference - also helped me a lot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Plugins have to defer every read of a mutable build model value (i.e. anything that can be set from a build script) until at least the end of the configuration phase. There are several ways to achieve this goal. Among them are:

- Using a Gradle API that accepts closures as values (e.g. `Copy.from`)
- Using callbacks like `project.afterEvaluate {}` or `gradle.projectsEvaluated {}`
- Using the convention mapping mechanism (note that this is not considered a public feature)

Choosing the best option for the job at hand requires some expertise. (It may help to study some of the plugins in the [Gradle codebase](https://github.com/gradle/gradle).) In your case, I might do the following:

```
project.task("abcTask", type: Copy) {
    from { project.abc.fromPath }
    into { project.abc.intoPath }
}
```

Your `<<` version doesn't work because it configures the `Copy` task too late. Generally speaking, all configuration should take place in the configuration phase, rather than the execution phase. You can learn more about Gradle build phases in the [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#build_lifecycle).